# Channel-based pipeline getting stuck

Tags: go

I am trying to build a pipeline for ingesting data with Go.  The 3 stages are "Download batches", "Transform each message", and "Enqueue messages into a queue".

The logic which seemed natural to me is to create 3 functions for each stage, and to tie these functions with unbuffered channels.

Somewhere in my code, I am not implementing channels correctly, or not using waitgroups?  As only 1 message gets to the final stage and program seems to stop/block.

```
    func (c *worker) startWork() {
        // channel for messages to be sent to the queue
        chMessagesToEnqueue := make(chan types.Foo)

        // channel for messages to be transformed
        chMessagesToTransform := make(chan []types.UpstreamFooType)

        // start the goroutines with the channels
        go c.startTransformer(chMessagesToTransform, chMessagesToEnqueue)
        go c.startEnqueuer(chMessagesToEnqueue)
        go c.startDownloader(chMessagesToTransform)
    }

    func (c *worker) startDownloader(out chan []types.UpstreamFooType) {
        // https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-soda
        // uses a library here to fetch data from upstream APIs, but the gist is:
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        for i := 0; i < c.workerCount; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                for {
                    // i've cut out some meat out to make more concise
                    var results []types.UpstreamFooType
                    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&results)
                    out <- results
                }
            }()
        }
        wg.Wait()        
    }

    func (c *worker) startTransformer(in <-chan []types.UpstreamFooType, out chan types.Foo) {
        data := <-in
        for _, record := range data {
            msg := types.Foo{
                name: record.fifa,
            }
            out <- msg
        }
    }

    func (c *worker) startEnqueuer(in <-chan []types.Foo) {
        data := <-in
        c.logger.Infow("startEnqueuer", "data", data)
    }
```

Comment: Your `startDownloader` and `startTransformer` don't range over their input channels. They each read one message, handle it, then return. `startDownloader` continues trying to send on its channel, but after the first message, nothing is receiving.

Comment: Thank you so much!    So ranging over a channel effectively dequeues the message, unblocking the channel?

Comment: Ranging over a channel continues to read until the channel is closed. It's like ranging over a slice, but for channels.